# Export several variables in one

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

In TS, I have **Class1** from *class.ts*, some functions from *helper.ts*, some variables from *variables.ts*:

For example, *variables.ts* looks like that:

```
export const test1 = 'test1';
export const test2 = 0;
export const test3 = 'test3';
export const test4 = 'test4';
```

Then with Webpack, I give the api.ts like the entry to build a module.

*api.ts*

```
export { Class1 } from './class1';
export { helper1, helper2 } from './helper';
export * from './variables';
```

Like this, in my webapplication, in JS, I import what I need from this module. However, instead of importing each variables like this:

```
import { test1, test2, test3, test4 } from 'api';
```

I would like to know if it was possible to import something like this:

```
import { variables } from 'api';
test1 = variables.test1;
```

or something like :

```
import { variables.test1, variables.test3} from 'api';
```

What should I change in the TS to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to import all variables as a *module namespace object*, then to export the object:

```
import * as variables from './variables';
export { variables };
```

See also: "module namespace object" in [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) from Mozilla.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a wrapper object named `variables`:

```
export const variables = {
  test1: 'test1',
  test2: 0,
  test3: 'test3',
  test4: 'test4'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how RXJS solves this problem:

`https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/umd.ts`

api.ts

```
export { Class1 } from './class1';
export { helper1, helper2 } from './helper';

import * as _variables from './variables';
export const variables = _variables;
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete Jack Bashfor answer, I would suggest `export default`

```js
// variables.js
export default const variables = {
  test1: 'test1',
  test2: 0,
  test3: 'test3',
  test4: 'test4'
};


// file.js
import nameYouWant from 'variables'
consol.log(nameYouWant.test1);
// ...
```